# thinking sphinx options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I'm confused, when should we use indexes and has method in sphinx. I have a very vague and abstract idea about it.I was told for date range we use has method. But nowhere I could find a concrete explanation for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indexes` method is for **fields** - and fields are the textual/string data that contain words you expect people to search for.

The `has` method is for **attributes** - which are mostly integers, floats, timestamps and boolean values, which are used by developers for sorting, filtering and grouping. If you want to filter for records given a date range, then an attribute is the best tool for the job.